# Announcer's Voice in "42"

Tags: character, 42

Was John C. McGinley recreating the voice of someone in particular as the baseball announcer in "42"? I've heard that kind of voice before, but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Walter "Red" Barber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Barber) was the announcer for the Brooklyn Dodgers when Jackie Robinson played.  And yes, McGinley is immitating Barber.  You can tell because he uses a few phrases during the course of the movie that are directly attributed to Barber, such as "Can of corn" and "Sittin' in the catbird seat".